# Please avoid onclick="window.location.href='…'" attributes and use proper links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, question-lists

The main page (and possibly other?) question lists now contain the markup

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/[id]/[title]'" class="cp">
```

to make list items clickable. However, this is not a proper link, and fails to be openable in new tabs using mouse gestures/middle button/shift clicks etc. I thought worked before, didn't it? It seems to [have been fixed in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72766/183280).

Comment: The *links* (titles) are still clickable, right? Just not other places on the containing div?

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, question titles are fine. The vote/answer/view counts are not.

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, it works on the titles. Do I misremember and I only used those to open the questions in new tabs?

Comment: Ok. That fix you reference is referring to something else, a UI element that no longer exists. The `onclick` containing div has been that way for *years*.

Comment: Dang. I was pretty sure I could do my mouse gestures on the vote/view count field. Regardless, even if it didn't work before, I'd love to have this behaviour - and divs inside anchors are valid with HTML5.

Comment: @Bergi is it properly valid, or does it do the "close the tag and reopen it again inside the div" thing it does with inline formatting tags?

Comment: @Random832: [properly valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: @Random832: Adding to that, the reason it was made valid in HTML5 is because no browser ever did that thing with <a> tags, which had the effect of the a element actually containing flow elements in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, switching between main and meta sites was accomplished via a little div hovering over the page.

That went away back in 2010, but while it existed [that bug report you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72766/183280) was filed (and fixed).

The clickable divs for lists are a separate thing - the titles are the links, the rest of the area is only clickable because of that `onclick` attribute and has been that way pretty much forever at this point.

I'd honestly forgotten about it, because I always just click the titles.

If you want this changed, we still have to deal with the whole "don't nest block elements (divs) in inline elements (a)" issue.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't read that linked answer properly. Indeed, [`onclick` seems to have been around since very long](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36772/183280)

Comment: "don't nest block elements (divs) in inline elements (a)" You're using the HTML5 doctype, which allows this because there has been interop for decades prior to HTML5, what do you have to worry about?

Comment: (Well I suppose there *are* issues with Chrome that you have to worry about - but these can very easily be worked around by setting `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the a elements depending on context.)